# Apex 5.0.2 version Session Id not fetched in wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

I used wwv_custom_flow_auth.std.login for login in one application. I used the code as following:

```
wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login ( p_uname => :P101_USERNAME,
                                 p_password     => :P101_PASSWORD,
                                 p_session_id => v('APP_SESSION'),
                                 p_flow_page  => :APP_ID||':5::SYS-X-TOOLS-LOGIN');
```

and getting error like :
[image]

So I think its unable to get App_session. I was running that application on Apex 5.0.2.

Though the same code is running fine on Apex 4.0.2. I ran it installing the same .sql exported KIT on other database with apex 4.0.2 version. Please give some suggestion. I am stucked.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you everything you need to know:

> Application "151" Page "gobbledegook" not found

This gives us a hint that `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login` is trying to parse your `p_flow_page` parameter and is trying to extract the Application ID and Page ID. It expects Page ID to be anything after the `:`.

You need to pass something like this:

```
wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login ( p_uname => :P101_USERNAME,
                             p_password     => :P101_PASSWORD,
                             p_session_id => v('APP_SESSION'),
                             p_flow_page  => :APP_ID||':5');
```

P.S. Normally there should be no need for you to directly call this (undocumented) procedure. Instead, use an Authentication scheme to implement your custom security.